# Convert Customer Relationships to Connection in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Can you please point me to a good guide on how to migrate Customer Relationship roles to Connections? I am using CRM 2013 on-premise.

I am going to try exporting the Roles and Importing them as Connections but this is giving me look up errors. In my opinion this is a simplistic approach and I might be wrong in the first place using this approach.

So has anyone tried this approach before and does it work? And is there an another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a blog about doing it using Scribe:
http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2011/10/crm-2011-converting-relationships-to-connections.html

Here is a blog about doing it using the built in import/export functionality:
http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/04/25/replace-relationship-roles-with-connections-in-dynamics-crm/

If I needed to migrate a large volume of relationships I would build the connection table based off the old relationship roles table using direct SQL injection.  Of course this is unsupported.